# display multiple images in jasper sub report dynamically using looping

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

I have one master report with sub report.

in master report display single value for each field but in sub report value fetched dynamically and multiple values.

in sub report i need to display num of images in loop.

how to apply this in ireport/jasper report ?

like

[image]

these images coming dynamically in sub report.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the subreport to use multiple columns and to fill horizontally.

Comment: can u pls give some example for same ?

Comment: Start with this sample that ships with JR: jasperreports-x.y.z/demo/samples/horizontal

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your images to InputStream dynamically. Then set image tags value expression to this input stream field.

i.e

```
InputStream inputStream= Convert your image to inputstream//
yourSampleJavaBean.setImage(inputStream);
```

now use yourSampleJavaBean.image variable as image expression value. It will change the images dynamically with each row.